# LISP check if list is symmetrical without reverse

Tags: lisp

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this... reverse is too slow, and I want to avoid using the function.

Basically I want to be able to return true if something like '(a b b a) comes up or '(a b c d c b a)

and false for something not symmetrical

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why using `REVERSE` is insufficiently efficient; have you actually profiled the solution? You just traverse the list once to do it; same as (say) finding the length of the list, and then you can traverse the two lists once to compare.

If you wanted to be a little fancier, you could simultaneously find the length of the list and reverse it using `LOOP` as so:

```
(defun fancier-palindrome-p (list)
  (let ((reversed '()) (length 0)) 
    (dolist (elt list)
      (incf length)
      (push elt reversed)) 
    (dotimes (i (floor length 2) t)
      (unless (eql (pop list) (pop reversed))
        (return nil)))))
```

This allows you to skip half the checks. I don't think this is worth the additional complexity. You can also use move down the list with a tortoise and hare to save half the consing at the cost of even more complexity.

```
 (defun ridiculous-palindrome-p (list)
   (let ((reversed-front '()))
     (loop  
       :for tortoise :on list 
       :for hare :on list :by #'cddr 
       :until (null (cdr hare)) 
         :do (push (car tortoise) reversed-front)
       :finally  
         (return  
          (if (null hare) ; length is even 
            (equal tortoise reversed-front)
            (equal (cdr tortoise)  
                   reversed-front))))))
```

Neither of these solutions strikes me as more compelling than

```
(defun palindrome-p (list) (equal list (reverse list))
```

If this really is a bottleneck, perhaps you'd be better off using vectors as your sequence representation to take advantage of the fast random access, like so:

```
(defun vector-palindrome-p (vector)
  (let* ((n (length vector)) (j n))
    (dotimes (i (floor n 2) (return t))
      (unless (eql (aref vector i) 
                   (aref vector (decf j)))
      (return nil)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't [this](http://gizmoworks.wordpress.com/2007/06/28/palindrome-in-lisp/) a good solution? Or you could search for other solutions by using "palindrome lisp" as keywords in your favorite search engine.

Comment: this conses quadratically in the length of the list, while the simple (equal list (reverse list)) conses linearly.

Answer (score 0):

This function avoids using reverse:

```
(defun palindromp (a)
   (or (null a)
       (null (cdr a))
       (and (equal (car a) (car (last a)))
            (palindromp (butlast (cdr a))))))
```

Comment: this conses quadratically, which is worse than reverse, which conses linearly.

Comment: I know :-) But I think the OP is asking too much: using reverse is about the best that can be done with linked lists. My answer is almost a joke: yes, it avoids reverse, but at some price... At least I find it quite elegant, not even using "if" (before macroexpansion !)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CommonLisp:

```
(defun pali (l)
  (labels ((scan (v n l)
             (or (>= n (/ l 2))
                 (and (equal (elt v n) (elt v (- l n 1)))
                      (scan v (+ n 1) l)))))
    (scan (apply #'vector l) 0 (length l))))
```

Have you used '`labels`' before!?  Here you go (in Scheme):

```
(define (palindrome? l)
  (let scanning ((v (list->vector l)) (n 0) (len (length l)))
    (or (>= n (/ len 2))
        (and (equal? (vector-ref v n) (vector-ref v (- len n 1)))
             (scanning v (+ n 1) len)))))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(defun   pal()

(format t "enter list")

(setf list1(read))

(print list1)

(setf list2(rev list1))

(if (equal list1 list2)

(print "palindrome")

(print "not palindrome")))


(reverse (list1)

(setf list2 nil)

(do ((i 1 (+ i 1)))((equal list1 nil)

(format t "reverse list")

(print list2))

(setf list2 (cons (car list1) list2))

(setf list1 ( cdr list1))))
```

Comment: Please don't simply post the code. Give some explanation or information or usage about your code. For example, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16893057/756941).