# jQuery click event not working after adding class

Tags: jquery

In my JSP page I added some links:

```
<a class="applicationdata" href="#" id="1">Organization Data</a>
<a class="applicationdata" href="#" id="2">Business Units</a>
<a class="applicationdata" href="#" id="6">Applications</a>
<a class="applicationdata" href="#" id="15">Data Entity</a>
```

It has a jQuery function registered for the click event:

```
$("a.applicationdata").click(function() {
    var appid = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#gentab a').addClass("tabclick");
    $('#gentab a').attr('href', '#datacollector');
});
```

It will add a class, `tabclick` to `<a>` which is inside `<li>` with `id="gentab"`. It is working fine. Here is my code for the `<li>`:

```
<li id="applndata"><a class="tabclick" href="#appdata" target="main">Application Data</a></li>
<li id="gentab"><a href="#datacollector" target="main">General</a></li>
```

Now I have a jQuery click handler for these links

```
$("a.tabclick").click(function() {
    var liId = $(this).parent("li").attr("id");
    alert(liId);        
});
```

For the first link it is working fine. It is alerting the `<li>` id. But for the second `<li>`, where the `class="tabclick"` is been added by first jQuery is not working.

I tried `$("a.tabclick").live("click", function()`, but then the first link click event was also not working.

Comment: Use 'on' event delegations

Comment: about event delegation, see this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Since the `class` is added dynamically, you need to use event delegation to register the event handler

```
$(document).on('click', "a.tabclick", function() {
    var liId = $(this).parent("li").attr("id");
    alert(liId);        
});
```

Comment: This also works if the entire element is added after the code's execution, fantastic!

Answer (score 19):

You should use the following:

```
$('#gentab').on('click', 'a.tabclick', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var liId = $(this).closest("li").attr("id");
    alert(liId);  
});
```

This will attach your event to any anchors within the `#gentab` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

Answer (score 13):

`.live()` is deprecated.When you want to use for delegated elements then use .on() wiht the following syntax

```
$(document).on('click', "a.tabclick", function() {
```

This syntax will work for delegated events

[**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 8):

Based on @Arun P Johny this is how you do it for an input:

```
<input type="button" class="btEdit" id="myButton1">
```

This is how I got it in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', "input.btEdit", function () {
    var id = this.id;
    console.log(id);
});
```

This will log on the console: myButton1.
As @Arun said you need to add the event dinamically, but in my case you don't need to call the parent first.

UPDATE

Though it would be better to say:

```
$(document).on('click', "input.btEdit", function () {
    var id = $(this).id;
    console.log(id);
});
```

Since this is JQuery's syntax, even though both will work.

Comment: is it `this.id` or `$(this).attr("id")` ?

Comment: Hey @ShijuKBabu I tried $(this).attr("id") and I got an exception. But this worked well on Google Chrome, are you using a different browser where it's failing?

Comment: I didn't try. I already got the answer for what I wanted. This is for input button. I was just asking, because I am using `$(this).attr("id")` to get id of current object and it works for me

Answer (score 2):

on document ready event there is no a tag with class tabclick. so you have to bind click event dynamically when you are adding tabclick class. please this code:

```
$("a.applicationdata").click(function() {
    var appid = $(this).attr("id");

   $('#gentab a').addClass("tabclick")
    .click(function() {
          var liId = $(this).parent("li").attr("id");
         alert(liId);        
      });


 $('#gentab a').attr('href', '#datacollector');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the another solution as well, the bind method.

```
$(document).bind('click', ".intro", function() {
    var liId = $(this).parent("li").attr("id");
    alert(liId);        
});
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I Know this is an old topic...but none of the above helped me.
And after searching a lot and trying everything...I came up with this.

First remove the click code out of the $(document).ready part and put it in a separate   section.
then put your click code in an $(function(){......}); code.

Like this:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    //your click code
    $("a.tabclick").on('click',function() {
      //do something
    });
  });
</script>
```