# Save ONE row of DataGridView to database

Tags: c#, datagridview, save

Guys I am trying to save ONE row of a DataGridView to a database.

Till now I have got examples where we need to SPECIFY the column names and numbers in z INSERT statemnt.
as below.

```
string col1 = datagridview1[0, datagridview1s.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        string col2 = datagridview1[1, datagridview1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        string col3 = datagridview1[2, datagridview1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        string insert_sql = "INSERT INTO YourTable(col1,col2,col3)VALUES('"+ col1 +"','"+ col2 +"','"+ col3 +"'");
        this.getcom(insert_sql);
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      { Message.Box(ex);}
     }
```

Is there any way to do the INSERT without having to hardcode the column details ?
I want to save the row in the database using the column headers of the datagridview as the column name in database.

Answer (score 0):

datadapter.update(datatable_name);

Comment: Please don't simply post the code. Give some explanation or information or usage about your code. For example, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16893057/756941).