# Create a toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, toggle

I have created a toggle buttons, when click on the any of the span for first time it will log "you click span"

then a new class will be added call "shareBtnToggle".

Upon second click on the same span with "shareBtnToggle" it should log "you click spans with shareBtnToggle class" and the class get removed, but in my code it doesn't work.

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/CFyHm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to catch event on object that can't be found in DOM. Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16893057/1051509)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this in one function. For simplicity I used add / removeClass but this could also be done using toggleClass.

```
$('.allsharebtns > span').on("click", function(){

    if ($(this).hasClass("shareBtnToggle")) {
        $(this).removeClass("shareBtnToggle");
        console.log("you click spans with shareBtnToggle class");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("shareBtnToggle");
        console.log("you click span");
    }


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EnBWT/1/

Comment: That is a more simplify modal, would use this instead. thanks