# Redirect to the same page after log out

Tags: php, session, logout

**index.php**

```
<ul class="top">
       <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) { ?>
        <li class="hover"><a href="#" onClick="revealModal('modalPage')">Login</a>
        </li>
         <?php } else {?>
        <li class="hover"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
           Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['login_user']; ?>
        </li>
         <?php } ?>
        <li><a href="registration.php" class="about">Registration</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php    
session_start(); 
session_destroy(); 
header('Location:index.php');  
exit;  
?>
```

I have my log out button in my every page, so i want that , if an user clicks in log out, he/she should redirect to the same page.. as i ve given the location page index here, but i want to remain in the same page.. any code to redirect to same page ?? Thank you in advance ..

Comment: You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` i.e header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: i ve already tried dis 1.. but givin me error

Comment: hey solved :) .. thankss

Comment: @user876345 hey that 1 z good but showing me wrror bcz i ve used sesiion after the page got redirected , it has lots of error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Approach 1**: In your **logout.php** file, you need to check if you have a REFERER url from previous page and redirect, if not, redirect to **index.php**

```
<?php    
session_start(); 
session_destroy();
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
 header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  
} else {
 header('Location: index.php');  
}
exit;  
?>
```

**Approach 2**: You can pass a reference to your login page to redirect.

Logout link

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>

<a href="logout.php?redirect=<?php echo base64_encode(curPageURL()); ?>">Logout</a>
```

**logout.php** file:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
session_destroy();
if(isset($_GET['redirect'])) {
 header('Location: '.base64_decode($_GET['redirect']));  
} else {
 header('Location: index.php');  
}
?>
```

Comment: hey cant i put a refresh word in that location header without giving '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  ??????????????

Comment: but its redirecting only to the index page.. i want to redirect it to the same page.. listen when i used this  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  , some problem arises like i ve used sessio  to call the data from different pages, so after log out the page showing lots of error.. did u get my point ?? @ignacio

Comment: Yep! have you seen my approach 2?

Comment: yeah .. dat 1 is only redirecting to the index page not to the same page

Answer (score 2):

How about,

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

In your login.php file:

```
$BackToMyPage = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(isset($BackToMyPage)) {
    header('Location: '.$BackToMyPage);
} else {
    header('Location: index.php'); // default page
}
```

Comment: i dint put the . operator so initially it was giving me error.. now dis 1 z working properly

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`if you want to redirect to the same page or refresh it.
**It could simply be done using**
 `header('Location : .');`

Comment: its not redirecting ... the page got stopped in logout.php page

Comment: It worked for me. I created a session before using header and it created it and then redirected to the same page.

Comment: no .. its not working ... i dont want to use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] bcz, i ve used session to call the data from diffrent page n after log out it's showing me error

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a parameter in your logout.php so you could dynamically redirect the user to the page he pressed the logout button.

```
<li class="hover"><a href="logout.php?page=homepage.php">Logout</a>
           Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['login_user']; ?>
        </li>
```

then in your logout.php

```
<?php    
session_start(); 
session_destroy(); 
$page = $_GET['page'];
header('Location:' . $page);  
exit;  
?>
```

Comment: i ve only one logout page for evey other page so i think it wont work

Answer (score 0):

```
$before = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(isset($before)) {
     header('Location: '.$before);  
} else {
     header('Location: index.php');  
}
exit;
```

Comment: Please don't simply post the code. Give some explanation or information or usage about your code. For example, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16893057/756941).

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    header('Location:index.php');  
}
```