# call detailview by using didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

My `viewcontroller` is using `UITableView` and i want to go to `detialView` by clicking on the row. Using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

I am working on storyboard but my `UITableView` class is not using Scene on `stroyborad` it made programatically and other class with is `detailView` with is a scene on the `Storyboard`.

But i’m unable to show my detailView , Trying so many ideas. In this i’m unable to use `segue` because `UItableview` Class is not a scene it made programtically and the other way to display `detialViewController` is using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ServiceDisplayViewController *serviceDisplayViewController =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"serviceDisplayViewController"];

    [self presentViewController:serviceDisplayViewController animated:NO completion:nil];


}
```

But it gives me error.

```
Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <SegmentsViewController: 0xa8757e0>.'
```

Can anyone please suggest me the best way to resolve this issue.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: serviceDisplayViewController will be nil..

Comment: Check the storyboard identifier

Comment: @Ramshad will be nil? can you please elaborate this.

Comment: @mak yes mak i already checked that.

Comment: Make sure that the 'Use Storyboard ID' checkbox is checked in Identity Inspector

Comment: see my answer and give the log details asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the identifiers are correct. then write the below code

```
UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryBoardName" bundle:nil];

if (mystoryboard != nil)
{
  ServiceDisplayViewController *serviceDisplayViewController = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ServiceDisplayViewController"];

    if(serviceDisplayViewController != nil)
    {
      [self presentViewController:serviceDisplayViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"%@", serviceDisplayViewController is returning as nil);
    }
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"%@", mystoryboard is returning as nil);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ServiceDisplayViewController *serviceDisplayViewController =
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ServiceDisplayViewController"];
Your Identifier should be your class name not object name
```

Comment: sory again the same error. 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <SegmentsViewController: 0x9bb48f0>.'

Comment: Please don't simply post the code. Give some explanation or information or usage about your code. For example, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16893057/756941).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //This is the line where your error is
    ServiceDisplayViewController *serviceDisplayViewController =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"serviceDisplayViewController"];
    //serviceDisplayViewController object does not get the correct object.
   // In the storyboard check whether the identifier name(serviceDisplayViewController) is correct or not. Check even for case-sensitive error
   //Also check self.storyboard object is also not nil



    [self presentViewController:serviceDisplayViewController animated:NO completion:nil];


}
```

[image]