# Conversion from string "&search" to type 'Integer'

Tags: sql, vb.net, type-conversion

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtsearch.Click

Dim SearchData = Search.StoredProcedure4(txtsearch.Text)
DataGridView1.DataSource = SearchData

End Sub
```

Conversion from string "&search" to type 'Integer' is not valid... How can I convert string into integer?

Comment: `&search` --  and how this string becomes an int?

Comment: because i`ll be putting number in search instead of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim SearchData = Search.StoredProcedure4(txtsearch.Text)
int SearchDataInt = Convert.ToInt32(SearchData ) //or (int)SearchData 
DataGridView1.DataSource = SearchDataInt
```

Just add this line between your define and display.

Comment: hey, where should i put this one? can you cite an example?

Comment: Please don't simply post the code. Give some explanation or information or usage about your code. For example, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16893057/756941).

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "&search";
foreach( char c in s)
{
Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToInt32(c));
}
```

Comment: byte[] LogoDataBy = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("&search");

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the fault that you have extracted the wrong value?
&search look like a parameter name in an URL, not the parameter value.

int.TryParse(stringValue, out intValue) is the way to go for parsing a string as an integer.