# How to handle class (made by jQuery) with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in jQuery. This time I tried to make a **double-stage effect** using jQuery.

For example, when you click the word, its color changed to red at first. And when you clicked it again, its color changed to blue.

So I used following code, but it doesn't work well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("p#origin").click(function () {
    $(this).css("color", "red");
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
  });

  $("p.clicked").click(function () {
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
  });
});
```

You can see the result at [here](http://codepen.io/pgmrhd/pen/qOQzwx)

I also tried this.

```
var toggle = 0;
console.log("toggle", toggle);

$(document).ready(function () {
  if (toggle == 0) {
    $("p#origin").click(function () {
      $(this).css("color", "red");
      toggle = 1;
      console.log("toggle:", toggle);
    });
  } else {
    $("p#origin").click(function () {
      $(this).css("color", "blue");
      toggle = 0;
      console.log("toggle", toggle);
    });
  }
});
```

Above code result can be seen [here](http://codepen.io/pgmrhd/pen/NGEQWP). The variable `toggle` is set to 1, but it doesn't work.

Is my question delivered well...? I'm new here, so I don't know how the javascript code loaded. (I also need help to study about this...)

I hope any solution to make a double stage effect. (Could anyone fix my above 2 codes to work well?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Click event not working after adding class using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893043/jquery-click-event-not-working-after-adding-class-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are dealing with dynamic selectors, ie you want the events handled to change based on dynamic evaluation of the selector, in that case you need to use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893043/jquery-click-event-not-working-after-adding-class-using-jquery/).

But in this case you don't need that, assuming at first the `p#origin` does not have blue color you can do something like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p#origin").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked").toggleClass('unclicked', !$(this).hasClass('clicked'));
  });
});
```

```css
#origin.unclicked {
  color: blue;
}
#origin.clicked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="origin">origin</p>
```

---

But if `p#origin` has blue color before the first click, then you can simplify it to

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p#origin").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
  });
});
```

```css
#origin {
  color: blue;
}
#origin.clicked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="origin">origin</p>
```

Comment: Aww, I was just going to post this... Nice answer though.

Comment: The link is the thing I needed. And your additional answer is quite helpful my study. How could you design the double .toggleClass? Thank you for nice answer.

Comment: The `toggleClass` method allows chaining so it returns you can call them like that

Answer (score 0):

*Just an idea instead of using `.class`:*

#### Loop an array of styles (you can use as many styles/steps you want)

```js
var c = ["#000", "#f00", "blue"];

$("#origin").click(function(){
  c.push(c.shift());                 // Put first array color to last place
  $(this).css({color: c[0] });       // Always use the 0 key
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="origin">Click to Toggle Color</p>
```

If you want to change **more** than just a **color**:

```js
var c = [
  {color:"#000",    background:"#ffe",    fontSize:16},
  {color:"fuchsia", background:"yellow",  fontSize:24},
  {color:"#1CEA6E", background:"#C0FFEE", fontSize:36}
];

$("#origin").click(function(){
  c.push(c.shift());
  $(this).css(c[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="origin">Click to loop styles</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just modified some JavaScript code from you, simply.

```js
    var $origin;
    $origin = $('#origin');
    return $origin.on('click', function() {
      if ($origin.hasClass('red')) {
        $origin.css('color', 'yellow');
        $origin.addClass('yellow');
        return $origin.removeClass('red');
      } else {
        $origin.css('color', 'red');
        $origin.addClass('red');
        return $origin.removeClass('yellow');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I checked your code and it works well! Does `return` makes this magic?

Comment: No problem :-) happy day~