# jQuery Click event doesn't work when I add a Class before

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I found this question but the solution is not working for me:
[jQuery click event not working after adding class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893043/jquery-click-event-not-working-after-adding-class-using-jquery)

I have this code:

```
$('.play_button i').click(function() {
    $('.content').css( "background-position-x", "-800px" );
    $(this).addClass('first_section');
});

$( '.play_button i.first_section' ).on( "click", function() {
    $('.content').css( "background-position-x", "-1500px" );
});
```

Why doesn't the `.on` function work?

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="play_button"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i></div>
</div>
```

Also I tried to make it work with `if` function, but it doesn't work either.

```
$('.play_button').on("click", "i", function() {

    if ( $( '.play_button i' ).hasClass( ".first_section") ) {
        $('.content').css( "background-position-x", "-1500px" );}
    else {
        $('.content').css( "background-position-x", "-800px" );
        $(this).addClass('first_section');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the html you are targeting?

Comment: HTML looks this:

<div class="content">
<div class="play_button"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i></div>
</div>

Comment: Check on() method doc, you arent delegating event....

Comment: I think i delegating event, please check my second example with if functions or maybe I don't understand you well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can rewrite your code so you just check the class inside same function:

```
$('.play_button i').click(function(){

    if ( !$(this).hasClass('first_section') ) {
        $('.content').css( "background-position-x", "-800px" );
        $(this).addClass('first_section');
    } else {
        $('.content').css( "background-position-x", "-1500px" );
    }

});
```

Your first snippet doesn't work because when you try to attach event handler `$( '.play_button i.first_section' ).on( "click", function(){..})` the element with class `first_section` is not in the DOM yet so nothing is attached.

Your second snippet will work if you correct `hasClass( ".first_section")` to `hasClass( "first_section")` - no dot required.

In general the best way to append events to elements that are not currently in DOM is to use `$("container").on("click","element",function() { ... });` where `element` is a jQuery selector for elements you want to bind to; and `container` is the element (e.g. div) that will hold newly created elements and already exists on page when you call this `on` method. Or just use `$(document)` if you have no any special container.

Comment: It's works, thank you! But I will Grateful if someone can explain why .on function don't work?

Comment: Ok so what should I do if I want to reload DOM, it is possible? For example i add class to element, and in next snippet I want to make click function on it with this new class added, how it should work?

Comment: You can attach an event handler right after adding a class to an element but in your case that wouldn't work because you will be attaching a new `click` handler every time the `i` is clicked ending up with growing number of handlers. For general approach see the update to my answer. Also check out - http://api.jquery.com/on/