# how to change css using jquery in twitter bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having collapsible panels in bootstrap

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading"> <h4> <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">ADDRESS</a></h4></div>
                        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                              <div class="list-group">
                                <?php

                                        echo "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>".$_GET['addr']."</a>";
                                ?>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

to which onclick I am toggling the class from panel-default to panel-primary using jquery and changing the css on particular click and onmouseover events. for Jquery I am using the code.

```
$( function() {
              $('.panel-default').click( function() {
                  $(this).toggleClass('panel-primary');
                $(this).find('a:first').css({'color':'white','text-decoration':'none'});
                } );

            $('.panel-primary').on('click',function(){

                $(this).toggleClass('panel-default');
                $(this).find('a:first').css({'color':'red','text-decoration':'none','font-size':'100px'});
            });

            $('.panel-default').on('mouseover',function(){$(this).find('a:first').css({'text-decoration':'none'});});

        });
```

but once it toggles back to panel-default from panel-primary its not changing the css of `a:first` and remains in white color.

Comment: use the `.first()` instead of `a:first`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are changing the class dynamically, your `$('.panel-primary').on('click',function(){..})` is not added to the button. In case of normal event handlers, it will register the handlers to only those elements which satisfies the selector when the registration script is executed.

[jQuery click event not working after adding class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893043/jquery-click-event-not-working-after-adding-class-using-jquery/)

In your case a more appropriate solution will be is to use the [collapse events](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events) and css like

```js
$(function() {
  $('.panel').on('shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('panel-primary', e.type == 'shown')
  })
});
```

```css
.panel.panel-primary a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4> <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">ADDRESS</a></h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="list-group">
        some content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```