# jQuery click not working after adding class but .on fires too soon to use

Tags: jquery

I am adding a class to a div similar to below:

```
$("#mainPopup").click(function() {
    $('.myPopupBox').show();
    $(this).addClass('popupMinus');
});
```

And then later have this click function based on the class added dynamically above:

```
$('body').on('click', '.popupMinus', function () {
  $('.myPopupBox').hide();
  $(this).removeClass('popupMinus');
});
```

I know that I have to use .on because the class is being added dynamically. ([here is the article I am referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893043/jquery-click-event-not-working-after-adding-class/16893057)) but when I have this code above, it fires the show and then the hide all at once so nothing looks like it is happening.

**Helpful information:**

- I do have everything is a document $(document).ready(function() { but I have tried putting the second function outside of it.
- I tried playing with the order of the functions. Didn't make a difference.
- If I don't include the second function (with the hide feature) then the first one with the show works perfectly.
- I have tried using delays - doesn't help

I'm sure that I am doing something dumb but can't find anything online that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over complicating this. You don't need to have 2 separate events. You are clicking on one button, so leave it as one click function, and then use `jQuery`'s `.toggle()` to toggle the elements visibility.

```
$(document).on('click', '#mainPopup', function(){
    $('.myPopupBox').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('popupMinus');
});
```

### **Documentation:**

**`.toggle()`** - http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

**`.toggleClass()`** - http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

**Note** - it should also be noted that by using `$(document).on()` you do not need to wrap it inside `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Thank you! That is much easier :) I figured it would be something easy like that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that clicking calls to 2 functions, you have to merge them in one function. Like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.popupMinus', function () {
  $('.myPopupBox').toggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('popupMinus');
});
```